# Error: TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer while trying to pick a random winner (Python)

Tags: python, string, random

I'm kind of new to programming and I've been trying to mess with Python a bit but while I was trying to make a random name picker that picks a random name from a list I always end up getting the same error .I also try to remove the winner that the code chose and add a new name to the 'winners' list but it doesn't seem to work. This is the short code I have right now.

```
winners = ["Wane", "Trevor", "Franklin", "Martoz"]
winner = random.choice(winners)
winners.pop(winner)
winners.append("Michael")
print(winners)
```

Comment: Post the error traceback as a separate code block. That makes it easier for us to spot the line with the error.

Comment: `pop()` requires the item's position within the list, not the item's value.  i.e. it wants something like `pop(0)` or `pop(5)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you provide an argument for method `list.pop`, that argument must be of type integer and represent the index of the element in the list.

Since your call looks like

```
winners.pop(winner)
```

and `winner` is a string, you'll get the mentioned error

> TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Also, I'm not sure what you really want to do, but you probably need to have two lists `participants` and `winners`. The following example draws two winners from the list:

```
import random

participants = ["Wane", "Trevor", "Franklin", "Martoz"]
winners = []

print("Participants before:", participants)
print("Winners before:", winners)

winner = random.choice(participants)
winners.append(winner)
participants.remove(winner)

winner = random.choice(participants)
winners.append(winner)
participants.remove(winner)

print("Participants after:", participants)
print("Winners after:", winners)
```

Which prints:

```
Participants before: ['Wane', 'Trevor', 'Franklin', 'Martoz']
Winners before: []
Participants after: ['Wane', 'Trevor']
Winners after: ['Martoz', 'Franklin']
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove an item from a list, use the `.remove()` function like so:

```
>>> winners = ["a", "b", "c"]
>>> winners.remove("b")
>>> winners
['a', 'c']
```

`.pop()` is used to extract an element from a list based on the index given, and returns the element removed from the list. Your error appears because you're trying to pop based off an element in the list (a name), as opposed to its index (its position in the list).

If you want to stick with `pop`, perhaps instead of choosing a random name, choose a random index in the list:

```
winners = ["Wane", "Trevor", "Franklin", "Martoz"]
winner = winners.pop(random.randrange(len(winners)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `.pop()`, just use `remove()`

```
winners = ["Wane", "Trevor", "Franklin", "Martoz"]
winner = random.choice(winners)
winners.remove(winner)
winners.append("Michael")
print(winners)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `pop()` function you should provide the index of `winner` in the `winners` list. This can be done by using `winners.index(winner)`

```
winners = ["Wane", "Trevor", "Franklin", "Martoz"]
winner = random.choice(winners)
winners.pop(winners.index(winner))
winners.append("Michael")
print(winners)
```

Result:

```
['Wane', 'Trevor', 'Martoz', 'Michael']
```